# Add The same button-ui icons to the different buttons with unique IDS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a series of buttons and some share the same icons. Presently I'm doing:

```
        $("#addNewStory").button({icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-plus'}});
    $("#addNewCampaign").button({icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-plus'}});
    $("#addNewAdItem").button({icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-plus'}});
```

Is there a neater way?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, if you want to make all elements having `id` "addNew*XXX*" to have that button, you could use

```
        $("[id^='addNew']").button({icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-plus'}});
```

Comment: That's Brilliant!! Thanks! So you are basically saying that if the id 'contains' then do action?

Comment: @Roger: Yes (technically, ["starts with"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)).

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple selectors in the same statement

```
$("#addNewStory, #addNewCampaign, #addNewAdItem").button({icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-plus'}});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorry, should have tried it first. Solution was just:

```
$("#addNewStory, #addNewCampaign, #addNewAdItem").button({icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-plus'}});
```